# Zend Installation on hosted Server

Tags: zend-framework

I have a hosted account.
I have WHM and cpanel access and have installed the Zend Guard.
I have extracted the Zend Framework files into my root directory.

Does this mean i am able to use the ZEND framework now ?
If not how do i install it. I am new to all of this.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend Framework is just a collection of PHP classes, it doesn't need "installation" as such. So yes, if you've put the files in your directory, you can use the framework.

You only need Zend Guard if your applications are encoded using it - this isn't related to Zend Framework in any way (except being made by the same company).

Comment: Ok Thanks. I am new to Zend and your help is appriciated !

How do i use the DB class in ZEND.

From beginning and setting my database information up to loading it when i need it.

Regards Matthew